# How to send item from ListView to another activity

Tags: java, android, listview

I am studding android so I m sorry about my question ...

I am trying to send name from the ListView when its clicked. I am trying to do smith by tutorials and get just this code but it don't work even when I try to call right method(President.getName())

```
`

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.util.Log;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import fi.antonina.task6.databinding.AdapterViewLayoutBinding;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        Log.d (TAG,"onCreate");
        ListView mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);


        //President objects

        President stahlberg =  new President("Stahlberg, Kaarlo Juho", "1919- 1925", "Eka presidentti");
        President relander = new President("Relander, Lauri Kristian", "1925 - 1931", "Reissulasse");
        President svinhufvudnew = new President("Svinhufvud, Pehr, Evind", "1931 - 1937", "Ukko-Pekka");
        President kallio = new President("Kallio, Kyosti", "1937 - 1940", "Neljas presidentti");
        President ryti = new President("Ryti, Risto Heikki", "1940 - 1944", "Nuorena Kustu Kalliokangas");
        President mannerheim = new President("Mannerheim, Carl Gustav", "1944 - 1946", "Marski");
        President paasikivi = new President("Paasikivi, Juho Kusti", "1946 - 1956", "Äkäinen ukko");
        President kekkonen = new President("Kekkonen, Urho Kaleva", "1956 - 1982", "Pelimies");
        President koivisto = new President("Koivisto, Mauno Henrik", "1982 - 1994", "Manu");
        President ahtisaari = new President("Ahtisaari, Martti Oiva", "1994 - 2000", "Mahtisaari");
        President halonen = new President("Halonen, Tarja Kaarina", "2000 - 2012", "Eka naispressa");
        President niinisto = new President("Niinistö, Sauli Väinämö", "2012 - 2024", "Owner of Lennu, the First Dog");


        //Add the Person objects to an ArrayList
        ArrayList<President> peopleList = new ArrayList<>();

        peopleList.add(stahlberg);
        peopleList.add(relander);
        peopleList.add(svinhufvudnew);
        peopleList.add(kallio);
        peopleList.add(ryti);
        peopleList.add(mannerheim);
        peopleList.add(paasikivi);
        peopleList.add(kekkonen);
        peopleList.add(koivisto);
        peopleList.add(ahtisaari);
        peopleList.add(halonen);
        peopleList.add(niinisto);
        PresidentListAdapter adapter = new PresidentListAdapter(this, R.layout.adapter_view_layout, peopleList);
        mListView.setAdapter(adapter);

        //to second activity
        mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onItemClick (AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){

                String str = mListView.getAdapter().getItem(position).toString();
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity2.class);
                intent.putExtra("myList", str);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }`
```

I understand its some small thing but I tried to do it all the day

```
public class President {
    public String name;
    private String date;
    private String freetext;

    public President(String name, String date, String freetext) {
        this.name = name;
        this.date = date;
        this.freetext = freetext;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getFreetext() {
        return freetext;
    }

    public void setFreetext(String freetext) {
        this.freetext = freetext;
    }


}






import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;


import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;


public class PresidentListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<President> {
    private static final String TAG = "PresidentListAdapter";

    private Context mContext;
    int mResource;
    private int lastPosition = -1;

    private static class ViewHolder {
        TextView name;
        TextView date;
        TextView freeText;
    }

    public PresidentListAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<President> objects) {
        super(context, resource, objects);
        mContext = context;
        mResource = resource;


    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        //get the persons information
        String name = getItem(position).getName();
        String date = getItem(position).getDate();
        String freeText = getItem(position).getFreetext();

        //Create the person object with the information
        President president = new President(name, date, freeText);


        //create the view result for showing the animation
        final View result;

        //ViewHolder object
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(mContext);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(mResource, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
            holder.date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
            holder.freeText = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);

            result = convertView;

            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
            result = convertView;
        }
        //animation
        Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(mContext,
                (position > lastPosition) ? R.anim.load_down_anim : R.anim.load_up_anim);
        result.startAnimation(animation);
        lastPosition = position;

        holder.name.setText(president.getName());
        holder.date.setText(president.getDate());
        holder.freeText.setText(president.getFreetext());
        return convertView;
    }
}



import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView t1;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main3);
        t1 = findViewById(R.id.textView7);
        t1.setText(getIntent().getExtras().get("myList").toString());
    }
}
```

Comment: Try using [`SharedPreferences`](https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/shared-preferences-in-android-with-examples/amp/) instead of `Intent.putExtra()`.

Comment: You haven't overriden `toString()` in your `President` class. What do you expect your call to `toString()` within `OnItemClick` to do? If you want to pass the selected `President` object into the next activity, `President` needs to implement `Parcelable`.